# How to customize Search Keyboard in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I want to customize my search keyboard in a way that if no input given in the text field the search button in keyboard should say "cancel" else if any thing is typed in the search text field it should say "search". How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't customize standart keyboard in iOS in a way of making **Done** button replaced by **Cancel** button. Try to find an alternative way to show user your **Cancel** button, e.g. on top navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

try this and tell me if it works

```
   - (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
    {

        for(UIView *subView in self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews){
            if([subView isKindOfClass:UIButton.class]){
                if([searchString length]>0           
                   [(UIButton*) setTitle:@"Search" forState:state:UIControlStateNormal];
                else
                   [(UIButton*) setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:state:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: That's the button in the topmost search bar, not the button inside the keyboard as requested. It also has some button related properties such as `showsCancelButton` that'll allow you to show the button without iterating subviews.

Comment: you just put up this code. This does not work. And I have not a controller, simply a Search Bar.

Comment: you can change "Return" into only one of these predefined labels with the returnKeyType property:

Return (default)
Go
Google
Join
Next
Route
Search
Send
Yahoo
Done
Emergency Call

Comment: @NihalSharma do u want to change the text on keyboard button or on searchbar button? clear it